# Banner image does not appear on Safari

Tags: css, safari, flickity

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I create a website with WordPress using Flatsome theme.

The website appears correcly in all browser except on Safari.
The problem is on the slider/banner image using Flickity that is not displayed on Safari.

Here are screenshots from Chrome and Safari for you to understand the problem:
[image: background image appearing on Chrome]
[image: image in slider does not appear on Safari]

By inspected the element, there are things that appear wrong:

1. the class bg-loaded used in the Flickity slider appears correctly on Chrome but not appear on Safari
   [image: dev tools Chrome - class bg-loaded appearing]
   [image: web inspector Safari - class bg-loaded not appearing]
2. it seems that there is a problem with Flickity: all Flickity class appear properly on Chrome but display a warning ! on Safari:
   [image: dev tools Chrome - flickity works properly]
   [image: web inspector Safari - problem with flickity]

The website works fine on iPhone.
All the other images within the webpages are displayed properly in all browsers and devices. This is only these banner images that are not displayed on Safari.

Can someone knows what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you very much for your help on this issue.

Regards.

Comment: Dear Stackoverflow Community, so no one have encountered this case before and no one can provide an advice or a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody could help on this issue please?